# ESX Host Upgrade

Tags: vmware-esx

Am going to upgrade the update manager. can any help me out for my below queries,

1. There are 3 methods,
2. Using Host Utilities
3. Using Update Manager
4. Using Script

Which method is easy to do, safer and best practices?

2. Before upgrading the host, what are the steps need to be done?
3. Putting the host in Maintenances mode or disconnect
4. remove from cluster

Did i missing anything?

3. While upgrading do you know any know issue in VMware?

recently i have upgraded VC 2.5 to 4. during database upgrade i got an error like "SQL throwing expections" then i came to know from vmware support team its a know issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have update manager on a different machine than VC, is that right?

If so is it a VM or physical?

If it's a VM I'd be tempted to just create a new v4 UM VM from scratch and either change the pointer to it in VC or use the same IPs.

If it's physical (and why would it?) then I'd still be tempted to wipe and rebuild - it doesn't take long and at least then it's 'clean'.

Comment: +1 for this, and same goes for ESX hosts using SAN storage. Just wipe them clean and install from scratch, to make sure that no "dust" from previous tickering are laying around :)